# Django: Filter matching objects using 2 fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, performance, django-4.1

I have the following classes:

```py
class Event(Model):
    ...

class IOCType(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)

class IOCInfo(Model):
    event = ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="iocs"
    ioc_type = ForeignKey(IOCType, on_delete=CASCADE)
    value = CharField(max_lenght=50)
```

Each event has one or several IOCs associated with it, which are stored in the IOCInfo table.

This is how my IOCInfo table looks like after creating some events:

| id | value | event_id | ioc_type_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some-value1 | eventid1 | 4 |
| 2 | some-value2 | eventid1 | 8 |
| 3 | some-value3 | eventid1 | 8 |
| 4 | some-value4 | eventid1 | 1 |
| 5 | some-value3 | eventid2 | 8 |
| 6 | some-value1 | eventid2 | 1 |
| 7 | some-value2 | eventid3 | 8 |
| 8 | some-value3 | eventid4 | 8 |

What I want to do is to take an event, compare its IOCInfo with those of other events and get back those events that match.

This is what I have done so far and it works, but I fear that as the database grows and the app has more users this query will end up being a bottleneck

```py
def search_matches(event):
    matches = Event.objects.none() 
    for ioc in event.iocs.all():
        matches |= Event.objects.filter(
            iocs__ioc_type=ioc.ioc_type, iocs__value=ioc.value
        )
    return matches.exclude(event=event.id)
```

If I pass the eventid2 to The above function, it will return eventid1 and eventid4 as expected.

Any suggestions to improve this function using any django method would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

1. Filter iocs that correspond to given event:

   ```
   iocs = IOCInfo.objects.filter(event=event)
   ```
2. Get events that has the same iocs (except the given one)

   ```
   events = Event.objects.filter(iocs__in=iocs).exclude(pk=event.pk)
   ```

That will result in a single pretty efficent query.

**UPD**:

To look into the fields of `ioc` - replace point 2 with the following:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(
    iocs__ioc__type__in=iocs.values_list('type', flat=True),
    iocs__ioc__value__in=iocs.values_list('value', flat=True)
).exclude(pk=event.pk)
```

Comment: I tried your function but it always returns an empty queryset, and it's because your query is comparing the ID of the iocinfo. This is what i looks like the query of your function `SELECT "event"."id', ... FROM "event" INNER JOIN "iocinfo" ON ("event"."id" = "iocinfo"."event_id") WHERE ("iocinfo"."id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "iocinfo" U0 WHERE U0."event_id" =  'eventid2') AND NOT ("event"."id" = 'eventid2'))`

Comment: Hi, I had to make a little change to make your function work and the avg is around `0,004 seconds`  for now is the best solution, the next one is around `0,010 seconds` and my original function is `0,019 seconds`

Comment: I forgot to say thank you.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understand...

```
def search_matches(event):
    get_values = lambda data, key: [x[key] for x in data]
    data_to_filter = evetn.iocs.all().values('ioc_type', 'value').order_by('id')

    return Event.objects.filter(
        iocs__ioc_type__in=get_values(data_to_filter, ‘ioc_type’),
        iocs__value__in=get_values(data_to_filter, ‘value’)
    ).exclude(pk=event.id)
```

Comment: I tried your function but it always returns an empty queryset, and it's because your query is comparing the ID of the iocs.

Comment: Fix: It is comparing IOCInfo ID, That field is unique so it will never return anything.

Comment: got it @wisvem, I updated the reply, take a look at it and let me know

Comment: Now it is working.  The avg is `0.010 seconds` . For now @egor-wexler solution is the best one with `0,004 seconds` avg.  Anyway thank you very much

Comment: Cool, I saw @egor-wexler’s reply  and I learned something new! :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should get the values of `ioc_type` and `values` for the IOCInfo of the eventid specified

```py
event_filters=IOCInfo.objects.filter(event=event).values(iocs__ioc_type=F("ioc_type"),iocs__value=F("value"))
```

then you should construct a `Q` object to filter the events according to either condition of `ioc_type` and `value` satisfied
finally,use this `Q` object to filter your event

```py
filtering_kwargs=Q()
for filter_ in event_filters:
    filtering_kwargs|=Q(**filter_)
matching_events=Event.objects.filter(filtering_kwargs).exclude(id=event.id)
```

Hope that solves your problem as db will be queried only twice no matter how large your data is

combining everything in a single function becomes

```py
from django.db.models import F
def search_matches(event):
    event_filters=IOCInfo.objects.filter(event=event).values(iocs__ioc_type=F("ioc_type"),iocs__value=F("value"))
    filtering_kwargs=Q()
    for filter_ in event_filters:
        filtering_kwargs|=Q(**filter_)
    matching_events=Event.objects.filter(filtering_kwargs).exclude(id=event.id)
    return matching_events
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your function but I had to change the kwargs to normal args to make it work but i got another error because the query is trying to filter `ioc_type` and `value` but those fields aren't part of the Event model. `matching_events=Event.objects.filter(filtering_kwargs).exclude(id=event.id)`

Comment: i've edited the answer you can now use `event_filters=IOCInfo.objects.filter(event=event).values(iocs_ioc_type=F("ioc_type"),iocs_value=F("value"))`

Comment: Tried and the avg is `0,007 seconds`, for now Egor proposal is the best one.  Thank you very much for your time and fr the explanation

Comment: I appreciate... @egor-wexler's answer is unbelievable.